# Getting Grey patch behind text in keyboard?

Tags: android, android-keypad

I am working on a keyboard and it shows grey shadow behind the text in the keyboard. how to remove that grey shadow behind the key.

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to have the XML or code. But try using `android:shadowColor="@android:color/transparent"` in your edittext view.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful to me. It works fine.
@James accept this answer.